# the definition of spinlock_t in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, spinlock

in include/linux/spinlock_types.h

the definition of spinlock_t like below

```
typedef struct spinlock {
        union {
                struct raw_spinlock rlock;
                struct {
                        u8 __padding[];
                        struct lockdep_map dep_map;
                };
        };
} spinlock_t;
```

why the "__padding[]" and "dep_map" variable should put inside a struct which has no name

but not just like below?

```
typedef struct spinlock {
        union {
                struct raw_spinlock rlock;
                u8 __padding[];
                struct lockdep_map dep_map;
        };
} spinlock_t;
```

is there any special meaning?

thank you

Comment: `but not just like below?` - In your code fields `__padding` and `dep_map` are **union**'ed (placed at same address), while in the original code they belong to single structure, so have **sequential layout**. As for absent of structure's field name, it simplifies reference to internal fields: `lock->dep_map` instead of `lock->field_name->dep_map`.

Comment: HI Tsyvarev, your explain very clear, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Because it is union of two structures and the other structure is enabled during debugging.
What you are trying to do is creating structure members that are not needed at all.And you should understand in union of two structures we can use one at a time.

```
typedef struct spinlock {
    union {
        struct raw_spinlock rlock;

#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC
# define LOCK_PADSIZE (offsetof(struct raw_spinlock, dep_map))
        struct {
            u8 __padding[LOCK_PADSIZE];
            struct lockdep_map dep_map;
        };
#endif
    };
} spinlock_t;
```